# SURF and SIFT algorithms doesn't work in OpenCV 3.0 Java

Tags: java, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.0 (the latest version) in Java, but when I use SURF algorithm or SIFT algorithm it doesn't work and throws Exception which says: `OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Specified feature detector type is not supported.) in cv::javaFeatureDetector::create`

I have googled, but the answers which was given to this kind of questions did not solve my problem. If anyone knows about this problem please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** The code below in third line throws exception.

```
        Mat img_object = Imgcodecs.imread("data/img_object.jpg");
        Mat img_scene = Imgcodecs.imread("data/img_scene.jpg");

        FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_object = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_scene = new MatOfKeyPoint();

        detector.detect(img_object, keypoints_object);
        detector.detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);
```

Comment: Can you post what you've done so far?

Comment: that's a bug in opencv's java wrappers, not your fault. even *if* you would get the opencv_contrib repo (where the SURF code was moved) and build it, the code in opencv/modules/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_manual.hpp, line 155, would not allow you to use it

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! As I understand from your comment there is no way to use these two algorithms in Java, am I right? If yes, it means that this is a popular problem for all who uses OpenCV with Java, then why OpenCV team don't solve this bug. Yesterday OpenCV was released the 3.0 version then how long we will wait this problem solved by OpenCV team. By the way can you tell me about other algorithm that work well in Java (Which one of other algorithm is good to use like FAST, STAR etc..) because I am new to these algorithms. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you compile OpenCV from source, you can fix the missing bindings by editing opencv/modules/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_manual.hpp yourself.

I fixed it by making the following changes:

```
(line 6)
#ifdef HAVE_OPENCV_FEATURES2D
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "features2d_converters.hpp"

...(line 121)
    case SIFT:
    fd = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
    break;
    case SURF:
    fd = xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
    break;

...(line 353)
    case SIFT:
        de = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
        break;
    case SURF:
        de = xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
        break;
```

The only requirement is that you build opencv_contrib optional module along with your sources (you can download the git project from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib and just set its local path on opencv's ccmake settings.

Oh, and keep in mind that SIFT and SURF are non-free software ^^;

Comment: Very thanks from your reply! I saw the part which you mentioned in the answer, you mean that I just un-comment the commented part? or??

Comment: Not just uncomment the part since it's slightly different (and won't work as it is), just edit it exactly as in my answer and it should compile and run fine^^ Remeber to re-copy the .jar and .dll (or .so) after re-building opencv to use in your java project!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful.

Comment: But one thing sir, that is in lines 121 and 353 which you mentioned above is not that as the file with me, e,g: is SIFT and SURF cases there is no `fd = xfeatures2d::SURF::create();` it is 'name = name + "SIFT"` and the same with surf. is in needed to add by me? if yes, then I can add, if no then why it not the same as your file. Thanks

Comment: fd = xfeatures2d::SURF::create(); is added by me, in place of 'name = name + "SIFT"' that I just deleted!  The point is to get that 'fd' and 'de' variable filled, that way it will run just fine ^^

Comment: My opencv generates the configuration files through cmake-gui. But it cannot be built. What could be the possible problem? Should I specify the whole path of xfeatures2d?

Comment: While making, I get the following error: fatal error: opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
What can I do?

Comment: You have to set OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH to <opencv_contrib>/modules of your opencv contrib project path in cmake gui while configuring!

Comment: Hi @Lake, I tried your solution and got following error:  " /home/sify/bin/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /home/sify/src/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_java310.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv11xfeatures2d4SURF6createEdiibb "    what's the problem?

Comment: @sify Did you set OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH to <opencv_contrib>/modules of your opencv contrib project path in cmake gui while configuring?

Comment: Yes, I'm using cmd line: "cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/sify/src/opencv_contrib/modules/ .."

Comment: Do you get that linking error during opencv compilation or at runtime?

Comment: Maybe you could try to use that build of opencv+extramodules with c++ to see if that linking error persists, as my guess is that it's unrelated to java.

Comment: In c++ it works with or without the changes to "features2d_manual.hpp". But because I'm using eclipse, I need to add "opencv_xfeatures2d" to "C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC C++ Linker->Libraries" and run "ldconfig" in console. Then it'll work. Maybe I should do something similar in eclipse to make the java wrapper work?

Comment: System.loadLibrary("libopencv_java310.so") should do it, I'm not sure why it gives you that linking error..

Comment: Having the same problem in windows, opencv_java310.dll is not being generated....this i suspect is due to an error " fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp': No such f
ile or directory (features2d.cpp)" which happens earlier

Comment: @BahramdunAdil, I found a way to fix it. You just need to copy everything under `opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/include/opencv2` to `opencv/modules/features2d/include/opencv2`. Then features2d_manual.hpp will pick up `'opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp` automatically. Be sure to re-install your newly built OpenCV Manager to your device afterwards!

Comment: crazy that you have to modify the source when all of the tutorials mention just including the extra modules to enable those algorithms. Have you thought about posting this as a commit?

Comment: Yeah, I've been wondering if this is just a bug of if they explicitly removed the bindings because of some issue with the licensing...  I'm more inclined to think they just forgot to patch java bindings when they removed SIFT and SURF from the main repo.

Answer (score 8):

That is because they are not free in newer versions of OpenCV (3+). I faced that problem some time ago. You have to:

1. Download OpenCV (if you have not)
2. Download the nonfree part from [opencv github repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)
3. Generate the makefiles with `cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` specifying the nonfree part with `DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules` option and build with `make -j8` (or whatever Java version you use)
4. Edit `features2d_manual.hpp` file, including `opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp` and including the necessary code for SIFT and SURF `case`, which are commented and not defined:
   `fd=xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();` for SIFT descriptor and `de = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();` for SIFT extractor. Do the same for SURF if you want to use it too.

I wrote this post explaining step by step how to compile the non-free OpenCV part in order to use privative tools like SIFT or SURF.
[Compile OpenCV non-free part](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/en/how-to-compile-opencv3-nonfree-part-from-source/).

Comment: do you have any idea how to generate cmake file in android studio?

Comment: Thank you for your post. I download 4.1.0 release and I only need to run cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules .. without editting any source.

Answer (score 1):

I believe changing features2d module (FeatureDetector class or any other classes from features2d_manual.hpp) to enable methods from OpenCV contrib modules is less attractive approach because it leads to circular dependency between the "core" OpenCV and extensions (which can be non-free or experimental). 
There is another way to fix this issue without affecting feature2d classes. Making changes in xfeatures2d CMakeLists.txt as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710250/build-opencv-with-contrib-modules-and-java-wrapper) leads to generation of java wrappers for SIFT and SURF - opencv-310.jar has org.opencv.xfeatures2d package now. Some fix was required in /opencv/modules/java/generator/gen_java.py. Namely inserted 2 lines as shown below:

```
def addImports(self, ctype):
if ctype.startswith('vector_vector'):
    self.imports.add("org.opencv.core.Mat")
    self.imports.add("org.opencv.utils.Converters")
    self.imports.add("java.util.List")
    self.imports.add("java.util.ArrayList")
    self.addImports(ctype.replace('vector_vector', 'vector'))
elif ctype.startswith('Feature2D'):                                           #added
    self.imports.add("org.opencv.features2d.Feature2D")                       #added
elif ctype.startswith('vector'):
    self.imports.add("org.opencv.core.Mat")
    self.imports.add('java.util.ArrayList')
    if type_dict[ctype]['j_type'].startswith('MatOf'):
        self.imports.add("org.opencv.core." + type_dict[ctype]['j_type'])
    else:
        self.imports.add("java.util.List")
        self.imports.add("org.opencv.utils.Converters")
        self.addImports(ctype.replace('vector_', ''))
```

After these changes wrappers are generated successfully. However the main problem still remains, how to use these wrappers from Java )). For example SIFT.create() gives the pointer to a new SIFT class but calling any class method (for instance detect()) crashes Java. I also noticed that using MSER.create() directly from Java leads to the same crash.

So it looks like the problem is isolated to the way how Feature2D.create() methods are wrapped in Java. The solution seems to be the following (again, changing /opencv/modules/java/generator/gen_java.py):

Find the string:

```
ret = "%(ctype)s* curval = new %(ctype)s(_retval_);return (jlong)curval->get();" % { 'ctype':fi.ctype }
```

Replace it with the following:

```
ret = "%(ctype)s* curval = new %(ctype)s(_retval_);return (jlong)curval;" % { 'ctype':fi.ctype }
```

Rebuild the opencv. That is it, all create() methods will start working properly for all children of Feature2D class including experimental and non-free methods. FeatureDescriptor/DescriptorExtractor wrappers can be deprecated I think as Feature2D is much easier to use.

BUT! I'm not sure if the suggested fix is safe for other OpenCV modules. Is there a scenario when (jlong)curval needs to be dereferenced? It looks like the same fix was suggested already [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/767).