# Is there any way that I can use SURF and SIFT ... in OpenCV 3 Java?

Tags: java, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3 which has a wrapper for Java, but I am not able to use SURF and SIFT and some other algorithms in Java. I have tried many ways and googled for a long time, but I cannot find any way for this problem. Also somewhere I even saw that some people says there is now way. Not only this, in Java wrapper I also cannot find `VideoWriter` class and also `BOWTrainer` class and so on. Now my question is why OpenCV has a wrapper which is not complete for Java, if   there are a lot of problems such as above I mentioned some, then it is no need to publish an incomplete wrapper for another language which is not usable for the users. Before OpenCV 3 I can write video, but now no. I waited for a long time that OpenCV 3 will be good version and will take care of all of the problem of previous versions, but now it has more problem then previous versions (not good documentation for Eclispe ... etc).   If anyone understanding my question and also has the way sole this, please tell me what to do. Thank you!

Comment: for SIFT and SURF I read this: `legacy, nonfree modules have been removed. Some algorithms have been moved to different locations and some have been completely rewritten or removed` SIFT and SURF both are nonfree algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed OpenCV wrappers manually and it works for me.  See my answer at [SURF and SIFT algorithms doesn't work in OpenCV 3.0 Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657774/surf-and-sift-algorithms-doesnt-work-in-opencv-3-0-java/35266046#35266046)

Answer (score 0):

```
U can implement sift in opencv3.
Here is the code...


package com.SR.view;

import static java.awt.Color.gray;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfKeyPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector;
import org.opencv.features2d.Features2d;


public class sift_opencv {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat blurredImage = new Mat();
        Mat hsvImage = new Mat();
        Mat mask = new Mat();
        Mat morphOutput = new Mat();
        Mat img;
        Mat maskedImage;
        //BufferedImage img;
        //img=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\softroniics\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SceneRecogintion\\src\\com\\SR\\view\\Penguins.png"));
        //File f= new File("C:\\Users\\softroniics\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SceneRecogintion\\src\\com\\SR\\view\\Penguins.png");

        img=Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\softroniics\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SceneRecogintion\\src\\com\\SR\\view\\burj.png");
        System.out.println(img);
        // remove some noise
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("out.png", img);
        Imgproc.blur(img, blurredImage, new Size(7, 7));

        // convert the frame to HSV
        Imgproc.cvtColor(blurredImage, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);


        //convert to gray
        //Mat mat = new Mat(img.width(), img.height(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
        Mat gray = new Mat(img.width(), img.height(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


        FeatureDetector fd = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);  
        MatOfKeyPoint regions = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        fd.detect(gray, regions);

        Mat output=new Mat();
        //int r=regions.rows();
        //System.out.println("REGIONS ARE: " + regions);
        Features2d.drawKeypoints(gray, regions,output );
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("out.png", output);

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am looking for SURF and SIFT, FAST is working for me too.

Comment: I think FAST is similar to SIFT. Getting the features of an object.

Comment: Do you know how to  configure opencv3 in a Netbeans  web project? Please.. its urgent...

Comment: Sorry I did not used, but configuring the OpenCV in Web project, Is there any error?

Comment: yup... Unsatisfied link error.. Error shown here... java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J

Comment: You can first put the OpenCV folder inside C drive e.g: C:\opencv then it must look like this: C:\opencv\build\java\x64. After init OpenCV like this: (init OpenCV while the web app come up for the first time)

Comment: And put this code while init:public static void loadOpenCVLib() throws Exception {
  String model = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
  String libraryPath = "C:/opencv/build/java/x86/";
  if(model.equals("64")) {
   libraryPath = "C:/opencv/build/java/x64/";
  }
  System.setProperty("java.library.path", libraryPath);
  Field sysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
  sysPath.setAccessible(true);
  sysPath.set(null, null);
  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
 }

Comment: I am using netbeans and I set the path as Project-properties-run- vmoptions as -Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64" . Am i correct??

Comment: I dint get what u mean  by init,where i can find init?

Comment: You said that you are using in Web App, maybe you will use Tomcat, I am right? then maybe you use Spring or what other framework, then any of the web app when the the server started will be initiated, then you can do some stuff in this time, for example maybe you register some listeners or what else, so here you also can add the OpenCV initialization stuff, then when your app started by Server (Tomcat) then, it will init itself then it will be ready for doing further work. Hope you understand my answer. Good Luck!