# Build OpenCV with contrib modules and Java wrapper

Tags: java, opencv, build

I'm trying to build OpenCV on my Windows 7 machine. To include the contrib modules I have added the OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH in CMake-gui. The opencv-300.jar and opencv-300.dll have been created but I can not find the Java classes to use the extra modules. Am I missing an option in the make configuration? Is it possible to use these extra modules from Java?

Comment: Hi! I am successfully build the OpenCV with extra modules and created the Jar file for Java, which I tested it was working well, but I did not see any new things in this Jar file, I mean that where the contrib code for Java, this Jar file is almost the same as the Jar file which came whit OpenCV download file. If you understand me the question, please tell me that  I did wrong some where in building Jar file Or it is like this? Thank you very much. Note: I have included everything while build Jar file

Answer (score 5):

i've the same problem and i resolved in this way. I imagine that you had downloaded from contrib repo the specific version match with the opencv version if you want to build. So go in  directory and enter, for example, face module directory; in this directory there is a file called CMakeLists.txt that you have to edit. This file should be like this:

```
set(the_description "Face recognition etc")
ocv_define_module(face opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_objdetect WRAP python)
# NOTE: objdetect module is needed for one of the samples
```

If you want to have the org.opencv.face package in your opencv-3xx.jar library you have to modify the 2nd line of the file in this way:

```
ocv_define_module(face opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_objdetect WRAP python java)
```

Then you have to compile opencv as depicted in the Readme.md of the contrib repo https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib

Obviously the same thing is valid for all the contrib modules if you want to add to your opencv-3xx.jar library.

I hope that this solution works for you, bye!

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the answer. You saved me really much time! If you want to automate things a little bit you can change directory to `opencv_contrib/modules` with `cd opencv_contrib/modules` and `grep -iR "WRAP python"`. If it print all of the occurrences of `WRAP python` that you want to replace with `WRAP python java` than you can run `find . -name CMakeLists.txt -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/WRAP python/WRAP python java/g'`.

Comment: I want to use surf in module xfeatures2d. I tried your solution but got errors while making:  opencv/build/src/org/opencv/xfeatures2d/DAISY.java:48: Error: sysmbol not found. what's the problem?

Comment: Hi, I had a problem that pointers to some internal objects are not supported. `Return type 'Ptr_Dictionary' is not supported, skipping the function`. Do you have an idea what need to be changed on module side to add support for java wrapper?

Comment: @sify try to import org.opencv.features2d.* in all your xfeaures2d files. this solved my errors.