# How to get well-defined edges regardless of the color

Tags: android, opencv, object-detection, edge-detection

I am trying to develop an App that detects cards "master cards, visa, cutomer cards, etc" using Android Camera, for that purpose i used OpenCV4Android version 3.0.0. To achieve this task, i did the following:

1- converted the frame taken from the camera to gray scale using

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(this.mMatInputFrame, this.mMatGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

2- blurring the frame using

```
Imgproc.blur(this.mMatGray, this.mMatEdges, new Size(7, 7));
```

3- apply Canny edge detector as follows

```
Imgproc.Canny(this.mMatEdges, this.mMatEdges, 2, 900, 7, true);
```

4- to show Canny's result on the real image, i did the following

```
this.mDest = new Mat(new Size(this.mMatInputFrame.width(), this.mMatInputFrame.height()), CvType.CV_8U, Scalar.all(0));
this.mMatInputFrame.copyTo(this.mDest, this.mMatEdges);
```

5- dialated the image using

```
dilated = new Mat();
Mat dilateElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, new Size(3, 3));
Imgproc.dilate(mMatEdges, dilated, dilateElement);
```

6- finding the contour of the card detected as follows:

```
ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
 hierachy = new Mat();
Imgproc.findContours(dilated, contours, hierachy, Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    if (Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i), true) > 90000) {
        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));

        if (rect.height > 60) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(mMatInputFrame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
            }
    }
}
```

When I run the App,

*Case 1*

if the card to be detected is of a homogenous color "the entire card is painted with the same color", Canny produces well defined edges which can easily detected as shown in the image "same-color-0" and "same-color-1". 
moreover, when i place the card that of a homogenous color on a table and move the camera around it, the edges are getting detected properly despite i am moving the camera. or in other words, the red frame that surrounds the edges of 
the card is always fixed around the edges and never disappears

*case 2*

if the card is not of a homogenous color "of a mixed colors", then the edge detection is bad as shown in image "mixed-color-0" and "mixed-color-1", and moreover, the red frame that surrounds the edges of the card disappears so often.
Another case extended from this case is, when the card is of two colors, one is light and one is dark, in this case, the edge detector detects only the dark part in the card because its edges are well defined as shown in image 
"mixed-color-2"

Please let me know how to get well defined and card-sized edges of the cards regardless of the color?
is there any other more accurate way for edge detection?

**same-color-0**:

[image]

**same-color-1**

[image]

**mixed-color-0**

[image]

**mixed-color-1**

[image]

**mixed-color-2**

[image]

**original images**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can try [structured edge detection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33318560/5008845). Please post original images also

Comment: @Miki original images posted

Comment: @Miki it seems that structuredEdgeDetection is not available in openCV4Android version 3.0.0. there is no such a class..please inform me if you have any information

Comment: It's in the contributo modules. I don't know if it's available in the java wrapper, or if you need to use JNI calls. I'll try that and post the results, you can then decide if it's a viable option or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Structured Edge Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d0/da5/tutorial_ximgproc_prediction.html).

I got these results running the C++ code in [this my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33318560/5008845). This seems like a good and robust result to me.

[image]
[image]
[image]

To use this in Java, you should know that *Structured Edge Detection* is in contrib module `ximgproc`.
You probably need to recompile OpenCV to use it: [Build OpenCV with contrib modules and Java wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710250/build-opencv-with-contrib-modules-and-java-wrapper)

Comment: i referred to this link https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/README.md   to know how to build opencv contrib . in the section titled "How to build OpenCV with extra modules", there are command started with $, what is it? is it the normal cmd in windows??!!

Comment: It's the shell, linux or Windows... I usually use cmake-gui, it'll be much easier

Comment: woud you please tell me, what is the is the difference between 2<opencv_source_directory>" and "<opencv_build_directory>"? both are mentioned in the same link.

Comment: _source_ is the folder where you have the source code for regular opencv you're about to compile (the one you downloaded). _contrib_ is the source folder for contrib modules, _build_ is the folder that will contain your compiled library

Comment: actually, i do not have in the opencv folder i downloaded any folder named "build". could it be "jni" or "libs"??

Comment: I compiled OpenCV way too much, but I've no experience with the Java wrapper. _build_ is a folder **you** make

Comment: actually, i tried to install opencv contrib modules in android but it does not work...dont know why...do not you have any other idea to solve this problem using normal opencv3.0.0?? thanks