# SURF and SIFT algorithms doesn't work in Open CV 3.0 Java

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0, sift, surf

I merge opencv and opencv-contrib from github repo

My Operating System is Windows 8.1

Proceed as follows:

#### 1.Download Github Repo.

```
opencv (Itseez/opencv)
opencv_contrib (Itseez/opencv_contrib)

D:\opencv_merge\opencv-master
D:\opencv_merge\opencv_contrib-master
```

#### 2. Download and Install CMake Lastest Version (current is 3.5.2)

#### 3. CMake Generate

```
(1)
Open CMake GUI 
setting path
source code: D:\opencv_merge\opencv-master
build the binaries: D:\opencv_merge\opencv-master\build
(2)
press 'Configure' 
wait for 'Configuring done'

watch output
---------------------

OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann hdf imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco java optflow stitching matlab python2
    Disabled:                    world contrib_world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev python3 viz cvv sfm

 Java:
    ant:                         C:/apache-ant-1.9.7/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.9.7)
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  YES
```

---

#### (3) setting OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH

```
D:/opencv_merge/opencv_contrib-master/modules

press 'Configure' 
watch output double check again
```

#### (4) Generate

#### 4. open OpenCV.sln

In `'Solution Explorer' CMakeTargets-->Install -->Right Click -->Build`

#### 5. get opencv-310.jar and opencv_java310.dll

```
(D:\opencv_merge\opencv-master\build\install\java)
```

#### 6. Netbeans setting

```
(1) add Opencv Library (add opencv-310.jar to Library)
(2) VM options: -Djava.library.path=D:\opencv_merge\opencv-master\build\install\java
```

#### 7. Run Project

#### 8. write some code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
.....
FeatureDetector orbDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
.....
FeatureDetector siftDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT);
.....
FeatureDetector surfDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
}
```

#### 9. run project and test

ORB detector can be executed (of course)

but SIFT and SURF detector cannot

[image]

---

I do a little modification after I saw this solustion: ( [SURF and SIFT algorithms doesn't work in OpenCV 3.0 Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657774/surf-and-sift-algorithms-doesnt-work-in-opencv-3-0-java/35266046#35266046) )

I edit `'D:\opencv_merge\opencv-master\modules\features2d\misc\java\src\cpp\features2d_manual.hpp'` according to the above URL and then begins the second step.

However, in the fifth step 'opencv_java310.dll' not be found in java folder(`D:\opencv_merge\opencv-master\build\install\java`)
I try same steps repeated at least 5 times but still no 'opencv_java310.dll'

The reason seems to be that I manually changed the 'features2d_manual.hpp'

I've been out all day :(

Who can help me solve this problem

Thank you guys

Comment: Instead of posting instructions from GitHub page, you should instead post link to the GitHub page and post your problem. Nobody would like to go through that long list to comprehend your problem. Please make it short.

Comment: Hi Sufian, Thanks for your opinion, I think that wasn't the code caused the error, so I confused why I merge that both of OpenCV Library the algorithms still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Guess your problem is that you need to recompile after manually modifying `features2d_manual.hpp`. That worked for me.

You can see my answer in *“[SURF and SIFT algorithms doesn't work in OpenCV 3.0 Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42657474/5032130)”*